# Implement advanced search

Tags: theme-development, search

I meet serveral problems when building my custom wordpress theme:

1 Avoid hard code the search url in the `searchform.php`.

A typical template may looks like this:

```
<form class="search" method="get" action="<?php echo get_search_link(); ?>" role="search">
    <input class="search-input" type="search" name="s">
    <button class="search-submit" type="submit" role="button">Search</button>
</form>
```

However notice the `action="<?php echo get_search_link(); ?>` the action is hardcoded, it assume that the search path is `http://homeurl/?s=xxx`, how about if a plugin change the search path to something like `http://homeurl/search?s=xxx`?

2 Change the search url

I do not like the default `/?s=xxx` path for search, I like something like `/search?s=xxx`

3 Advanced search with more query variables

I want to search with keywords+category+tag+meta value, like this:

[image]

I have to set the search url form each link in the panel and hightlight it once it is the current query variable.

Is this possible,?

---

(The updated problem have been post in a new post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/244088/104900))

According to cybmeta's answer, I make the following change:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'include_any_post_type_in_search');
function include_any_post_type_in_search($query)
{

    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query()) {

        $tax_query = array(
            'relation' => 'AND'
        );

        if (isset($_REQUEST['c'])) {
            $cate = $_REQUEST['c'];
            array_push($tax_query, array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'terms' => sanitize_text_field($cate)
            ));
        }


        if (isset($_REQUEST['t'])) {
            $tag = $_REQUEST['t'];
            array_push($tax_query, array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'terms' => sanitize_text_field($tag)
            ));
        }
        $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);

    }
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'cyb_query_vars');
function cyb_query_vars($vars)
{
    array_push($vars, "t", "c");
    return $vars;
}

function my_get_search_url($key, $val)
{
    $query = array();

    $supported = array("c", "t", "k");
    foreach ($supported as $s) {
        if ($s == $key) {
            array_push($query, "$s=$val");
        } else {
            $old_val = get_query_var($s);
            if (isset($old_val) && !empty($old_val)) {
                array_push($query, "$s=$old_val");
            }

        }
    }
    return get_search_link(join("&", $query));
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
                <?php
                $cates = get_categories();
                foreach ($cates as $cate) { ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo my_get_search_url('c', $cate->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cate->name; ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
```

It generate url like:`/search/c%3D9`:

1 The `c=9` is encoded

2 It render the index page rather than the search result page.

And once I visit `/?c=9&s=1` I can get results with keyword `1` and category 9 .

Got the index page for `/?c=9`.

Got 404 for `/search?c=9`

Seems like there are some rewrite problem.

Comment: 1. yes, it is possible. 2. Questions should be about code or core concepts there is no point in asking broad theoretical questions as the answer is usually short and not very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `get_search_link()` and someone [filter the search URL](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/search_link/) and change it,  `get_search_link()` will return the filtered URL; that is the great of non-hardcoded URL. You or third party plugin may modify the URL and it will always return the correct value. So, issues 1 and 2 seems to not exist.

The issue 3 has different approachs:

1.- Use inputs in the search form with a `name` equal to some query argument directly accepted by `WP_Query` as query string. For example, [`category_name`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters):

```
<form class="search" method="get" action="<?php echo get_search_link(); ?>" role="search">
    <input class="search-input" type="search" name="s">
   <select name="category_name">
        <option value="">All categories</option>
        <option value="politics">Politics</option>
        <option value="economy">Economy</option>
    </select>
    <button class="search-submit" type="submit" role="button">Search</button>
</form>
```

2.- Use whatever query string you want and hook `WP_Query` on search request in `pre_get_posts` action:

The HTML:

```
<form class="search" method="get" action="<?php echo get_search_link(); ?>" role="search">
    <input class="search-input" type="search" name="s">
   <select name="a_search_filter">
        <option value="">All categories</option>
        <option value="politics">Politics</option>
        <option value="economy">Economy</option>
    </select>
    <button class="search-submit" type="submit" role="button">Search</button>
</form>
```

And the action:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cyb_advanced_search' );
function cyb_advanced_search( $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        // Set query parameters you need
        // For example
        $search_filter = $_REQUEST[ 'a_search_filter' ];
        $tax_query = [
            'taxonomy' => 'news',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    =>  sanitize_text_field( $search_filter ),
        ];
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

    }
}
```

I would add the query string to WP Rewrite system:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'cyb_query_vars' );
function cyb_query_vars( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = 'a_search_filter';
  return $vars;
}
```

Now you use `get_query_var()` to get the value of the custom query variable:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cyb_advanced_search' );
function cyb_advanced_search( $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        // Set query parameters you need
        // For example
        $search_filter = get_query_var( 'a_search_filter' );
        $tax_query = [
            'taxonomy' => 'news',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    =>  sanitize_text_field( $search_filter ),
        ];
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

    }
}
```

Finally, you can get the current request and add/remove classes to your links and highliting them as you wish using CSS:

```
if( get_query_var(  'a_search_filter' ) ==  'category1' ) {
    $class = 'selected';
}

<a href="..." class=".<?php esc_attr_e( $class ); ?>.">Category 1</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. And do you mean that all the accepted query arguments can be used directly in the search url as query variables like the `category_name` ? I never know that :(

Comment: Not all query argument, only the accepted as query string. For example, you can use `https://example.com/?s=keyword&category_name=politics` and the search results will look for `keyword` in posts that belong to `politics` category. Unfortunately, I don't know the exact list of the arguments than can be used directly as query string, but the argumetns you see in [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) with the format `key=value` should work, including `post_type`, `author` and lot more.

Comment: OK, I got it. I will have a try. BTW, seems there are some inconsistent function calls in your codes.

Comment: Sure, I didn't test it, just written here. Fixed.

Comment: I almost make it work, with just one problem, I have update the post, can you have a check if possible?

Comment: It seems you have a different problem. It may be better if you post a new question and include what the function `my_get_search_url()` does and what result you expect. `/?c=9` loading index and `/search?c=9` given 404 error seems correct to me unless you code a different behaviour for such URLs; by default, WordPress recognize a search query ([`is_search()` returns `true`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_search/)) only if `s` query var is set ([see L1646 (WP 4.6) in wp-includes/query.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1646)..

Comment: Find I create a new post:http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/244088/104900